# How to insert secret question and answer using ASP.NET membership?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-membership, user-roles

I am using asp.net membership for my web application.I need my users to choose their own secret question and answer in a separate page after their successful login.

What is the method to insert the secret question and answer into database using asp.net membership?

Answer (score 3):

The procs name should be [aspnet_Membership_ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer]

with parameters

```
@ApplicationName       nvarchar(256),
@UserName              nvarchar(256),
@NewPasswordQuestion   nvarchar(256),
@NewPasswordAnswer     nvarchar(128)
```

Or in code

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.changepasswordquestionandanswer.aspx

But you need the password for that one

Comment: That is the problem for me.How can i get the password for the logged-in user?.I thing there is no method to get the password in asp.net membership(Correct me if i am wrong). Is there any other solution to get the password?

Comment: either ask the user for it again or store it from the previous page (not recommended)

Comment: Ya i m storing the password in session.Though this is not a better way,this may be the only solution for this issue..